# net_ntoa, struct sockaddr_in and pointer cast

Tags: c, network-programming

for the third line in the following snippet:

```
char cli_ip[20];
struct sockaddr cliaddr;
.......
memcpy(cli_ip, inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)cliaddr)->sin_addr), 20);
```

I got errors:

> udp_receiver.c:96:41: error: cannot convert to a pointer type
>   udp_receiver.c:96:41: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘memcpy’ makes
>   pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>   /usr/include/string.h:44:14: note: expected ‘const void *
>   **restrict**’ but argument is of type ‘int’

what is reason for this?

Comment: -1 Never change the question completely after you got answers! - If you have another problem ask it as a new post.

Comment: As @MM. noted, please do not edit your questions in this manner. Your new error is clearly a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included headers appropriately?

man of `inet_ntoa` suggests following to include

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

It might be case that compiler does not find prototype of `inet_ntoa` and assumes that it returns `int` and then gives warning in `memcpy`.

Comment: ah, OK, it is because of `#include <arpa/inet.h>` is missing in my source codes, thanks